# PHP Replace consecutive occurrence of characters in sentence

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to replace all consecutive characters in each WORD if there are more than three (three being the most possible in German language, two for English so I know the output example is grammatically wrong).

Example input:

```
Hellooooo Louis, whaaaaaat's up pal?
```

Expected output:

```
Hellooo Louis, whaaat's up pal?
```

I tried to change:

```
preg_replace('/(\w)\1+/', '$1', $word);
```

to

```
preg_replace('/(\w)\3+/', '$1', $word);
```

However, it doesn't output anything.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_words_in_English_with_tripled_letters

Comment: @foxbeefly: ha, didn't know they had 3 in english too :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
((\w)\2{2})\2+
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/tG1dI6/1)

Replace with `$1`.

[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/mLz1Oq):

```
$re = "#((\w)\\2{2})\\2+#"; 
$str = "Hellooooo Louis, whaaaaaat's up pal?"; 
$subst = "$1"; 
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
echo $result;
```

Output:

```
Hellooo Louis, whaaat's up pal?
```

**EXPLANATION:**

We capture the symbol with `(\w)` - it is Group 2 value. Then, we check if it is followed by the same character with `\2{2}` exactly 2 times, and we capture it into Group 1. Then, we match any more identical subsequent characters with the `\2` backreference.

Comment: thanks workd perfectly. I'll accept the answer when I can in few minutes!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to go:

```
preg_replace('/((\w)\2\2)\2+/', '$1', $word);
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use `\K` for resetting after and replace with empty, which is a bit more efficient:

```
(\w)\1\1\K\1+
```

See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/wF0jT8/1)